# How do I install Mozilla Thunderbird using terminal?

Tags: 20.04, snap, thunderbird

I found snap package in snapcraft but the developer isn't from Mozilla. How do I install Mozilla Thunderbird using terminal?

Comment: Thunderbird is developed by a community, not by Mozilla. The plan was announced some years ago. https://techcrunch.com/2015/11/30/thunderbird-flies-away-from-mozilla/

Comment: How would you start it if it was a snap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thunderbird exist in main default [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/thunderbird), should this suffice for you.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

If you looking for newest version, follow the instruction from [Mozilla's website.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux)

> 1. Download Thunderbird from the Thunderbird download page to your home directory.
> 2. Open a Terminal and go to your home directory: `cd ~`
> 3. Extract the contents of the downloaded file: `tar xjf thunderbird-*.tar.bz2`
> 4. Close Thunderbird if it's open.
> 5. To start Thunderbird, run the thunderbird script in the thunderbird folder: `~/thunderbird/thunderbird`
>
> Thunderbird should now start. You can then create a launcher on your
> desktop to run this command.

However, this requires you to create launcher and install any dependencies by yourself— pretty inconvenience compared to former way.

Comment: I see, I have installed Thunderbird now. Thank you for answering my question.